# Importing files from a Java package that gets created at run time

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, grpc, grpc-java

I am using grpc for which the proto files are generating Java POJO like files at run time, in a separate package. I am trying to create integration tests for these services and this hence trying to refer these generated file classes in my tests. But since they get created at run time, I'm get compiler errors everytime my pom file changes. What is the right way to add this project that generates this above mentioned Java package at run time, into my project, so that I can refer its classes? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually you use interfaces (at compile-time) and let your generated classes implement those interfaces. You then can simply refer to the interfaces in your code and load the generated classes at run-time.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. grpc generates code at compile time via protoc. I think you need to include what error you get and your Maven protoc configuration, because the problem isn't runtime vs compile time.